# Can't include .eps files

Tags: latex

I can't include `.eps` files. I do

```
\userpackage{eps2pdf}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{feb2/M45det_om3c.eps}
\caption{blabla}
\label{fig:m45det_om3}
\end{figure}
```

I've read I need to use DVI but I can't understand how to do this on MIKTEX. There's no such option in the drop-down list, but  `PDFLATEX+MAKEINDEX+BIBTEX`.
How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use *either* DVI *or* the “eps2pdf” package, not both. On Windows, chances are you don’t want to use DVI — so don’t.

On the other hand, you need to fix your code (remove the file extension from your image filename) and the pdfLaTeX invocation (add the `--shell-escape` option). See the discussion at [“Why can't pdflatex print EPS figures?”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383/42) for more information.

Comment: I get Sorry, but "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe" did not succeed. You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.  when adding the --shell-escape option in the Preferences menu. What's wrong?

Comment: @Peter Well I don’t use MiKTeX but simply googling for “texify” and “shell escape” is very informative.